# Easyphp Web Setup

Tags: php

I've tried to setup an EasyPHP in local and make it visible from the Web via DynDNS, which I've already successed many times before, but now this just doesn't work, maybe I've forgotten something...

*The "server" is a common workstation.

Here is what I have done :

1) Installed EasyPhp (with a index.php/html file in WWW folder)
2) Changed the port in the config to port 80
3) Forwarded port 80 to the server IP in my router configuration
4) Added the server to the router DMZ

*Also tried removing antivirus/firewall

I've installed PortListener, pointed it on port 80, and when I access "myname.dyndns.com" it says

> Client connected
>     GET / HTTP/1.1
>     Host: xyz.dyndns-remote.com
>     User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; fr; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>     Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>     Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>     Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>     Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>     Keep-Alive: 115
>     Connection: keep-alive

So the server is accessible via Web, receive the connection successfully, but in my browser it says that the connection failed and show nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Does it run on http://127.0.0.1 ??
Can you publish the address so that I can see the error?

Comment: Yeah it runs on 127.0.0.1, and even via Web it open the Port...but receive nothing.